# TinyMCE won't let me superscript and strips out my sup tags

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I downloaded TinyMCE latest version 4.3 from https://www.tinymce.com/.

Everything is working fine but for some reason it wont let me superscript at a start of a sentence and it sometimes lets me superscript at the end of the sentence. I can't duplicate the conditions.

When I try to go into code enter the sup tags it strips them out.

```
 <sup>1</sup>wont allow blah blah blah sometimes allow<sup>1</sup>
```

How do i disable stripping out/removing my super scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake in my config file

i had set

```
valid_children:  p[strong|a|#text|br]
```

i just add to add sup to to that list before i had

```
valid_children:  p[strong|a|#text|br],sup
```

should be

```
valid_children:  p[strong|a|#text|br|sup]
```